# How to read and write to imported pre populated SQLite Database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite

newbie in Android kotlin. I have imported a prepoluated SQLite Database thru SQLiteOpenHelper.

Problem : When I do a find with below code. I got error : this database is not writable

```
fun findProduct(productname: String): Product? {
val query =
```

"SELECT * FROM $TABLE_PRODUCTS WHERE $COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME =  \"$productname\""

```
val db = this.writableDatabase

val cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null)

var product: Product? = null

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    cursor.moveToFirst()

    val id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))
    val name = cursor.getString(1)
    val quantity = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2))
    product = Product(id, name, quantity)
    cursor.close()
}

db.close()
return product
```

}﻿

I would like to know 
1) can do CRUD and Find on imported pre-populated SQLite Database?
2) how to reference this imported SQLite Database?  
can use this:  val db = this.writableDatabase

Thanks

Comment: This is not a solution, but a suggestion. If you are starting off, why not try `Room` DB for all this. It will make your life extremely easy. Here are a few links:<br/>
[Using Room Database | Android Jetpack](https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-android-jetpack-675a89a0e942)<br/>
[Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)

Comment: Before using Room and JetPack thing, Is there a solution for my problem? Thanks

Comment: @MilkBottle needs showing database import opening